# When java crashes with "X Window System error" are any logs produced?

Tags: java, x11

I have a Java GUI program that occasionally crashes with the following output:

```
(java:830): Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'java' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'RenderBadPicture (invalid Picture parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 16758 error_code 146 request_code 143 minor_code 7)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
/bin/sh: line 1:   830 Trace/breakpoint trap   /usr/java/oracle-jdk-1.8.0_u131/jre/bin/java ...
```

but I cannot seem to find any details what it was doing at the time, eg. a Java stacktrace.

Are there any logs produced in this situation?  Or do I need to use "trap" and "--sync" to debug the underlying C code?

Comment: _(Without any knowledge on the topic:)_ for logs search under **/var/logs**.

Comment: Is there a `hs_err_pid<pid>.log` file in your working directory? If possible, the hotspot VM will write those when it crashes.

Comment: No such file is in the working directory.